# Is it possible to create branches of git subtrees while maintaining parent repo structure?

Tags: git, git-subtree

We are looking to put sub-projects within a Git repository. The repo, i.e. ParentRepo, will need to sync with our private server, and then a few subdirectories will need to also push to a company github repo and pull from upstream github repos. We also need the ability to make branches from those subdirectories (not the entire parent repo) that will be pushed to github.

So our hierarchy is something like:

- ParentRepo/Dir1/GitHubProj1
- ParentRepo/Dir1/GitHubProj2
- ParentRepo/Dir1/PrivateProj

GitHubProj1 and GitHubProj2 are forks from community github repos. We need to be able to grab upstream changes from the community github repos and branch from our github repos. PrivateProj will not push or pull from any github repos. Everything gets pushed to our ParentRepo on our private server.

We considered using submodules, but there seem to be many complaints about them so we decided to try using subtrees instead. We made subtrees using the company github account URLs and added remote tracking branches for the outside github accounts.

However, when we tried making a branch of a subtree using the git subtree split command with --branch option, the subtree's contents were put at the root of the parent repo.

When we create a branch of each subtree, we would like to maintain its original directory structure within the parent repo. Aside from using special nomenclature, is there any way to make branches in this way or to set up our repo differently so this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

when you use git subtree split and branch it makes that branch for the subtree only. It's true the branch is part of the parent project so switching to that branch could wind up removing a lot of files and then reconstructing them when moving back which is kind of annoying.

Your best alternative is probably to clone the github repo locally (somewhere outside of your ParentRepo path) and optionally branch. Then you can resort back to the simple push and pull subtree commands, directly to your local copy, and do your push up to github from there.

This is effectively doing the same thing as you were doing with split but in one step so you don't have to swap to the temp-branch after splitting, and then merge that somewhere, swap back to the original branch and delete the temp-branch.

Comment: I hope that's not confusing :P  I'm adding subtree to tortoisegit if that's any use to you.